# Using .h files to failsafe interaction between .c files?

Tags: c

I'm a novice C programmer, and I was recently reading the section in Code Complete about limiting communication between subsystems, and I had an idea and I'd like to know if it's considered bad practice or if there's a better way to go about it.

The idea is to us .h files as a sort of interface between the .c files representing the subsystems in my program.  For example, if I have specific functions in A.c that I want to be able to have called in B.c, while there are other functions in A.c that I want to call from D.c, but I want to create a failsafe so that if I (or someone else) screws up and tries to call an A.c function for B.c in D.c, it won't compile.  To achieve this, one can make separate .h files (maybe called AtoB.h and AtoD.h) which only include the prototypes for functions to be used in their respective files, instead of just having an A.h file that is included in B.c and D.c with the prototypes for both groups of functions.

Is there a better way to go about creating this kind of failsafe?  If not, is there any reason not to do what I described above, other than the extra work it would take to create and manage those extra .h files?  I'm guessing one drawback could be readability (having someone open up my source code and think "...wtf am I looking at??"), since I haven't heard of people using .h files this way before.  TIA!

Comment: That sounds sensible. The system I'm working on at the moment does the same.  It has several libraries, each with a public interface in a .h file.  Every library also has a mock version, for use in unit tests, that uses the same public interface plus has a second interface that the unit tests themselves use.  The unit tests do not use the standard .h file and the other components do not use the test .h file.  Enforcing which header file another module can #include is different matter.

Comment: Oh cool, good to know this isn't some wacky out-there idea.  Thanks!

Comment: There are a number of uses for function/data hiding through the use of differing headers. You are simply determining which source files you want to expose the contents contained in each of the various headers to. One good example and fair explanation of the use and benefits is [**Object Oriented C**](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf). IIRC Chapter 2 provides an example of this type implementation.

Comment: That book looks interesting, I'll check that out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way to do it is to split A.h into several files, each with a subset of functions that belong together functionally. Let's call these `feature1`, `feature2`, et c.

The start of B.c could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "feature1.h"
#include "feature3.h"
```

If you want to stress that using a new feature is a big deal, then you could move the includes to a separate file so that each .c only includes a single .h file:

Binternal.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "feature1.h"
#include "feature3.h"
```

B.c:

```
#include "Binternal.h"
```

Personally, I think this gives a better structure. With your proposed way, the same prototype will be present in multiple include files, which would give run-time errors if you forget to change one of them.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that instead of having the .h files being based on the relationship between .c files, I can have .h files representing a subset of functions, the point being that if a subset of functions is used in multiple other .c files, I won't have to worry about changing the prototypes multiple times if I add or change functions?

Comment: I forgot to ask- what's the point of the Binternal.h file?  If it's only included in B.c, wouldn't that effectively be the same as having all those includes in Binternal.h directly in the B.c file?

Comment: Yes, the compiler won't notice the difference. But it adds an extra step for the programmer when he wants to use another feature. The purpose would be to make the programmer think twice before adding the use of another feature.